# Controller isn't counted as a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I have many different controllers throughout this project and all of them are declared the same way. This one now isn't getting called/giving an error and I have no clue why. I've looked through it and it all looks right to me.

I think it's probably some syntax error I'm not seeing. If its something else please tell me. I'm trying to learn angular and everything helps. Also if you need anything else just tell me.

I've made sure its not that the app.js name got changed and been looking for missing syntax but can't find anything.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=companyDepartmentController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

company-department-controller.js

```
app.controller('companyDepartmentController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'companyService', function ($scope, $timeout, companyService) {

    /**
    * Create/Manage Company Departments & Shifts
    *
    */

    // INITIALIZE VARIABLES *********************************************************************************

    var vm = this;
    vm.Departments = [];
    vm.activeDepartment = {}
    vm.departmentBeforeEdit = {};
    vm.activeShift = {};

    vm.OffsetString = "";

    vm.SaveDepartmentSuccessMessage = null;
    vm.SaveDepartmentErrorMessage = null;

    // STARTUP **********************************************************************************************

    (vm.GetDepartments = function () {
        companyService.GetDepartmentsWithShiftInformation().success(function (data) {
            console.log('hi');
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i])
            }
            vm.Departments = data;
            // for now we are limiting this to 1
            vm.activeDepartment = vm.Departments[0];
            vm.setTimeZoneOffsets(vm.activeDepartment);
        });
    })();

    // move to global location?  handle this better?
    (vm.findLocalOffsetString = function () {
        console.log('hi1');
        vm.OffsetString = moment(new Date()).format('ZZ');
    })();

    // $BROADCAST/$ON EVENTS ********************************************************************************



    // EVENTS ***********************************************************************************************

    vm.saveDepartment = function (department) {
        // new
        if (department.DepartmentID === 0 || typeof department.DepartmentID === 'undefined') {

        }
        // update
        else {
            companyService.UpdateDepartmentHeader(department).success(function (data) {
                vm.SaveDepartmentSuccessMessage = "Saved!";
                resetDepartmentMessage();
                department.InEdit = false
            });
        }
    };

    vm.editDepartment = function (department) {
        vm.activeDepartment = department;
        vm.departmentBeforeEdit = angular.copy(vm.activeDepartment);
        vm.activeDepartment.InEdit = true;
    };

    vm.cancelDepartmentEdit = function (department) {
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.Departments.length; i++) {
            if (department.DepartmentID === vm.Departments[i].DepartmentID) {
                vm.Departments[i] = vm.departmentBeforeEdit;
                vm.departmentBeforeEdit = {};
                vm.activeDepartment = vm.Departments[i];
                break;
            };
        };
    };

    vm.addShift = function () {
        if (!vm.activeDepartment) return;

        vm.activeShift = {
            DepartmentID: vm.activeDepartment.DepartmentID,
            StartTime: new Date(),
            LocalStartTime: new Date(new Date() + vm.OffsetString)
        };

        vm.activeShift.StartTime.setSeconds(0);
        vm.activeShift.LocalStartTime.setSeconds(0);
    };

    vm.deleteShift = function (shift) {
        if (!shift) return;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the shift: " + shift.Name + "?")) {
            companyService.DeleteShift(shift).success(function () {
                angular.forEach(vm.activeDepartment.Shifts, function (c, i) {
                    if (c.ShiftID === shift.ShiftID) {
                        vm.activeDepartment.Shifts.splice(i, 1);
                    };
                });
            });
        };
    };

    vm.setTimeZoneOffsets = function (department) {
        if (!department || !department.Shifts || department.Shifts.length === 0) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < department.Shifts.length; i++) {
            department.Shifts[i].LocalStartTime = new Date(department.Shifts[i].StartTime + vm.OffsetString);
            department.Shifts[i].EndTime = moment(department.Shifts[i].StartTime).add(department.Shifts[i].Duration, 'hours').toDate()
        };
    };

    var fixTimezoneOnSave = function (shift) {
        shift.StartTime = new Date(shift.LocalStartTime).toLocaleString();
    };

    vm.setActiveShift = function (shift) {
        if (!shift) return;
        vm.activeShift = angular.copy(shift);
    };

    vm.saveShift = function (shift) {
        fixTimezoneOnSave(shift);
        // new shift
        if (shift.ShiftID === 0 || typeof shift.ShiftID === 'undefined') {
            companyService.AddShift(shift).success(function (data) {
                shift.ShiftID = data;
                vm.SaveDepartmentSuccessMessage = "Saved!";
                resetDepartmentMessage();
                getUpdatedShiftsAndInfo();
            }).error(function (e) {
                vm.SaveDepartmentErrorMessage = e.error;
                resetDepartmentMessage();
            });
        }
        // updating existing
        else {
            companyService.UpdateShift(shift).success(function (data) {
                vm.SaveDepartmentSuccessMessage = "Saved!";
                resetDepartmentMessage();
                getUpdatedShiftsAndInfo();
            }).error(function (e) {
                vm.SaveDepartmentErrorMessage = e.error;
                resetDepartmentMessage();
            });
        }
    }

    var getUpdatedShiftsAndInfo = function () {
        companyService.DepartmentAndShiftInformation(vm.activeDepartment.DepartmentID).success(function (data) {
            vm.activeDepartment.DepartmentShiftInformation = data.DepartmentShiftInformation;
            vm.activeDepartment.Shifts = data.Shifts;
            vm.setTimeZoneOffsets(vm.activeDepartment);
        });
    };

    var resetDepartmentMessage = function () {
        // clear error/success message if they have values still
        if (vm.SaveDepartmentSuccessMessage != null) {
            $timeout(function () { vm.SaveDepartmentSuccessMessage = null; }, 2000);
        }
        if (vm.SaveDepartmentErrorMessage != null) {
            $timeout(function () { vm.SaveDepartmentErrorMessage = null; }, 2000);
        }
    };

    // create controller object in console if we have logging turned on
    if (spectrum.LoggingEnabled) {
        spectrum.logController(vm);
    };

}]);
```

_CompanyDepartment.cshtml

```
<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-controller="companyDepartmentController as cd">
</div>

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/companyDepartments")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
}
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.mask', 'ui.select', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'angular.filter', 'smart-table', 'colorpicker.module'])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        //make delete type json to facilitate passing object
        //to our generic method.
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers["delete"] = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        };
    });
```

Comment: Very first thing I can say is, `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/companyDepartments")` should be loaded last. though wondering error should be different than what you are having now

Comment: In my other html files it's always loaded first. But i'll put it at the bottom. I have a lot of commented out code in my html file if that would make any difference? The entire class is basically commented out until I fix this error.

Comment: What does your Jasmine test code look like, and does it work from there?

Comment: What does Jasmine test code mean?

Comment: @user4648142 [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html) is a framework used to test JavaScript code.   If you are doing any type of real Angular development, you will need to have that or another framework like Mocha integrated or you will run into many problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a naming issue with the controller(which I can't see), I would imagine your issue dealing with the company-department-controller.js not being loaded.

In setting up your angular project, I would suggest that you follow [this angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).  It has been very helpful to me in creating a well structured project.

Comment: My problem is the fact that I just came into this code base and I'm still a junior programmer so it would be to difficult/time consuming for me to redo big sections of the code base. And we don't have any seniors on this project either.

Comment: @user4648142, okay that makes sense.  Have you confirmed that the actual controller file is being loaded?